# Traduction de « effectiveness » — « efficacité » ou « effectivité » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Une collègue m'a demandé récemment de relire une traduction, dans laquelle elle utilisait le mot « effectivité » (pour *effectiveness*). Spontanément, je voulais lui recommander d'utiliser plutôt « efficacité », mais en vérifiant, j'ai constaté qu'[« effectivité »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/effectivit%C3%A9) existe bel et bien.

Quel est le meilleur choix ? Quelle est la différence entre les deux ?

Comment: Je dirais a priori que ça dépend du contexte ! « Efficacité » s'emploie aussi bien pour des concepts que pour des personnes, « effectivité » ne s'emploie en principe que pour des concepts.

Comment: Ça me rappelle les fameux 3E enseignés en Management (Effectiveness, Efficiency and Economy).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Les deux mots ont des sens différents (et peuvent correspondre à « effectiveness ») :

**Efficacité :** relatif à quelque chose qui fonctionne bien.
**Effectivité :** relatif à quelque chose qui est tangible.
*et aussi* **Efficience :** évalue le degré d'efficacité.

D'instinct, j'aurais dit « efficacité ». Après recherche, mes dictionnaires proposent aussi le même mot. Comme l'indique votre source, « effectivité » est rare. J'opterais donc pour « efficacité ».

Cela étant dit, peut-être que le contexte ([droit international](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/effectivit%C3%A9/27904), par exemple) fait que le choix de votre collègue est plus pertinent.

Comment: Pour ajouter: *effectivité* correspond à un adjectif différent d'*efficace* (on emploi beaucoup plus communément l'adverbe qui lui correspond: *effectivement*).

Comment: *efficience* qualifié la capacité d'une personne ou d'un système à atteindre ses fins, son objectif avec le minimum de moyens possibles.